# Why was Tyrion not sold for a fortune as originally planned?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In Game of Thrones S05E06, Jorah and Tyrion are captured by slave traders. Tyrion is only spared because apparently, his cock has magic powers, and can be sold for a fortune.

In S05E07, Tyrion is bought on a whim, only because the buyer thinks Tyrion is funny. The buyer paid for Tyrion with the few coins he was playing with in his hand, while he paid a small sack of coins for Jorah.

The few coin(s) paid for Tyrion is hardly the fortune mentioned in previous episode. Why would Tyrion's captor sell him for so little, instead of finding a cock merchant as originally planned?

Comment: As you could sell him also without his Johnny (which would then give twice a revenue), this could also just have been intimidating. Some guys tell secrets, when it's about the rockethelmet. Like "you better spare me because 10 armed folksmen are hiding a few meters away."

Comment: Perhaps the slave trader was discovering that finding a well-funded cock merchant was not as easy as first imagined.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> “Feel free. We will have it tanned and stuffed and sell it for a fortune. A dwarf’s cock has magical powers.”
>
> **A Dance With Dragons**

I don't think everybody believed that dwarf’s cock has magical powers. Especially in Westeros were parents don't like dwarf kids because if everybody believed that dwarf’s cock has magical powers they would have hunted down all the dwarfs.

I haven't seen the episode yet but in the books Tyrion was sold as dwarf who could amuse people.

> Lot ninety-seven.” The auctioneer snapped his whip. “A pair of dwarfs, well trained for your amusement.”
>
> The auction block had been thrown up where the broad brown Skahazadhan flowed into Slaver’s Bay. Tyrion Lannister could smell the salt in the air, mingled with the stink from the latrine ditches behind the slave pens. He did not mind the heat so much as he did the damp. The very air seemed to weigh him down, like a warm wet blanket across his head and shoulders.
>
> “Dog and pig included in lot,” the auctioneer announced. “The dwarfs ride them. Delight the guests at your next feast or use them for a folly.”
>
> **A Dance With Dragons**

Because it feels like people weren't really interested in buying a dwarf. I say this because Tryion was sold as clown rather than a person possessing a cock of magical powers.

Comment: That's a good answer for the books, but the TV canon is different.

Answer (score 8):

I think a lot of it has to do with human tendencies to favor more immediate gains over higher, longer term gains.  If the slave trader would have hold out, he wouldn't have gotten the gold immediately, and he would have had to hunt down a merchant to sell off Tyrion's member.  Instead, he's got gold directly in front of him without having to go through extra hassle.

Comment: Also, if he held out, he might have been stuck enduring Tyrion's sarcasm, sly jokes and on-the-knuckle observations for *months*... :-)